# Remove Apache

Tags: apache, macos, system-administration

I have multiple installations of apache on my Mac OS X 10.5 and would like to remove them including any dependencies.

They are installed in 3 different directories.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: why do people vote the question down? stupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man. OSX comes with Apache. So why and how did you install the other 2?

I hope you used MacPorts to install the other 2 (and if you did they'd have to be different versions). Then it's an easy process. Other then that, you'll have to remove by hand. Make sure the installations you don't want do not start with the system. Then remove the directories.

Also, take a look at  [MAMMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.php). Yes it comes with PHP and MYSQL, but they can be stopped (turned off). And it's so easy to remove - just delete the folder.

Comment: i re-installed it but in the wrong directory so hence the multiple instances. I did not use MacPorts so it looks like I am having to go and do it manually.

thanks

Comment: i've spent a good 6 hours just making apache2 to in /Library/apache2/ work and we're good to go. I've separately left the other instance alone but with only one instance running.

Comment: Yeah good idea. I have the installed Apache "turned off". And installed XAMPP. Easier control over mods (in Apache and PHP).